# Scrambled output when using OpenMP for XOR cipher

Tags: c, encryption, parallel-processing, openmp, xor

I have the code below in C which is a simple XOR cipher and I am trying to parallelize it using OpenMP. I have added a simple 'for' directive and it causes scrambled output. I would appreciate it if someone can help me understand why this is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "omp.h"

void encryptDecrypt(char inpString[]) 
{ 
    // Define XOR key 
    // Any character value will work 
    char xorKey = 'P'; 
  
    // calculate length of input string 
    int len = strlen(inpString); 
  
    // perform XOR operation of key 
    // with every caracter in string
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    { 
        inpString[i] = inpString[i] ^ xorKey; 
        printf("%c",inpString[i]); 
    } 
} 
  
// Driver program to test above function 
int main() 
{ 
    char sampleString[] = "GeeksforGeeks"; 
  
    // Encrypt the string 
    printf("Encrypted String: "); 
    encryptDecrypt(sampleString); 
    printf("\n"); 
  
    // Decrypt the string 
    printf("Decrypted String: "); 
    encryptDecrypt(sampleString);
    printf("\n"); 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

Sample output without OpenMP:

> Encrypted String: 55;#6?"55;#
>
> Decrypted String: GeeksforGeeks

Sample output with OpenMP:

> Encrypted String: 5##6?"55;;5
>
> Decrypted String: GesfoGeresekk

Comment: Note that it is very unlikely that you will achieve any speedup unless the strings are "bigly yuge",  because entering and leaving a parallel region takes time, and there is very little work inside the parallel region. (Of course, you may be doing this for educational reasons, rather than to attain performance :-)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenMP threads don't run in any specific order unless you explicitly ask them to do so.

You should perhaps remove the `printf` from the loop and put it outside after the loop has executed (all threads have executed) and then print the string for deterministic output.

Interestingly your string contains the correct encrypted and decrypted value. Just the printing order is incorrect.

```
[..]

#pragma omp parallel for 
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
{ 
    inpString[i] = inpString[i] ^ xorKey; 
    // printf("%c",inpString[i]);  Remove this
}

[..]

// Encrypt the string 
printf("Encrypted String: "); 
encryptDecrypt(sampleString); 
printf("%s\n", sampleString);  // Add print here

[..]
```

Answer (score 0):

### "Geeks" let you *Grab a speck* <sub>( actually there are --2-- specks prepared there ... )</sub>

The `#pragma omp parallel for`-block was an obvious trick to confuse `omp`-freshmen, yet there was another surprise, that  Mohit has expressed in these words:

> ***Interestingly your string contains the correct encrypted and decrypted value.***

---

[image]

yet,
the part of modifying the string was clean and sound, there was actually **nothing indeed "interesting" there** ( awfully inefficient, yes, yet fully legal ). It is an ordered, mutually non-interacting, plain `[i]`-aligned, straight modification of the **`sampleString[]`** disjunct `char` values, but the attempt to get all those `printf()`-s produced individual `(char)`-s put "back" on a single row, in a clean and human-readable sequence was the speck number one ( that was obvious ).

[The **program** <sub>( inside the live-analyser-debugger-IDE )</sub>](https://godbolt.org/z/ZVnO6R) `stdout` however reads, as if the first ( properly ordered ) `(char)`-s must have been identical in "**Ge**...for**Ge**..." ( so as to produce an equally **`XOR`**-ed output `(char)`-s "**55**...**55**..." in the `XOR`-modded strings, don't they have to?

```
[13]: -->GeeksforGeeks<--
NEXT: will encrypt the original String:
[13]: -->55;#6?"55;#<--
[13]: -->55;#6?"55;#<--
NEXT: will decrypt the (now) encrypted String:
[13]: -->GeeksforGeeks<--
[13]: -->55;#6?"55;#<--
```

And the **`XOR`**-ed prints also look somehow "shorter", don't they?
**Heck they do** and for a reason :o) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . to confuse you

```
[37]: -->GagarinGonnaGroomGreetingsGospelGoers<--
NEXT: will encrypt the original String:
[37]: -->171"9>?>>1"??="55$9>7#?# 5<?5"#<--
NEXT: will encrypt the original String:
[37]: -->171"9>?>>1"??="55$9>7#?# 5<?5"#<--
[37]: -->171"9>?>>1"??="55$9>7#?# 5<?5"#<--
NEXT: will decrypt the (now) encrypted String:
[37]: -->GagarinGonnaGroomGreetingsGospelGoers<--
[37]: -->171"9>?>>1"??="55$9>7#?# 5<?5"#<--

Platform's sizeof(char) was 1
```

Feel free to read the **`line 49`** in the live-IDE above and may experiment further with this **Double-Speck**